# Docker Compose: Set variable in php.ini from Dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I have a small Docker network based on [this package](https://github.com/aschmelyun/docker-compose-laravel) for Docker Compose and Laravel. I'd like to set the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` variables in `php.ini` to allow for larger file uploads.

Is this possible? Or is there an alternative approach? I expected to find lots of similar questions on the web, but it's not that many and typically they concern some existing image, while I create the PHP image from a Dockerfile.

This is from `docker-compose.yml`:

```
php:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: php.dockerfile
  container_name: php
  volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www/html
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
  networks:
    - laravel
```

This is `php.dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html
 
RUN apk add --no-cache zip libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own `php.ini` locally and `COPY` it in your dockerfile for instance.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did. I also came across the idea of [inline replacements](https://davescripts.com/docker-container-how-to-change-php-settings-inline-replacements) using `sed`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a sample of overriding some php.ini values instead of editing the php.ini directly.  [image]

[image]